# Im having troubles with python(tkinter) gui with the layout

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

```
# Import module  
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui, time
  
# Create object  
root = Tk() 
# Adjust size  
root.geometry("350x350")

root.title("SycoBak's SpamBot")
  
# Add image file 
bg = PhotoImage(file = "Slogo.png") 
  
# Create Canvas 
canvas1 = Canvas( root, width = 350, 
                 height = 350) 
  
canvas1.pack(fill = "both", expand = True) 
  
# Display image 
canvas1.create_image( 0, 0, image = bg,  
                     anchor = "nw") 
                     
canvas1.create_text(250,250, text="SycoSpamBot")


L1 = Label(canvas1, text="Word")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(canvas1)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
canvas1.create_window(100, 100, window=L1)    

L2 = Label(canvas1, text="Amount")
L2.pack( side = LEFT)
E2 = Entry(canvas1)
E2.pack(side = RIGHT)
canvas1.create_window(100, 150, window=L2)  
  

def Spammer ():
  time.sleep(5)
  x = 0
  amount = int(E2.get())
  word = E1.get()
  while (amount > x):
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    x=x+1
    
button1 = Button(root, text = "Start", command=Spammer, bg="green") 
button1_canvas = canvas1.create_window( 100, 10,  
                                       anchor = "nw", 
                                       window = button1) 
root.mainloop()
```

Im wondering if I could make it so that the start button is at the bottom, and the word and amount labels are on the left side of a text input box.
This is how my GUI layout currently looks like. (Very Messy)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYvtU.png

Comment: Use `grid()` for efficiency.

Comment: @CoolCloud: `grid` isn't any more efficient than `pack`. Different, but no more nor any less efficient. They each have strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @BryanOakley Perhaps you are correct. I meant grid offers easy positioning, nothing else.